# Zend layout.phtml not rendering

Tags: zend-framework2, config

I have two controllers: "Home" and "Login" in an "Application" module. In the first controller, layout.phtml is correctly loaded, but in the second controller, layout.phtml isn't loaded. I want that the layout is be loaded in the two controllers. Here is my module.config.php file:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Home',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
                'constraints' => [
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ]
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'pt_BR',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Home' => 'Application\Controller\HomeController',
        'Application\Controller\Login' => 'Application\Controller\LoginController'
    ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/home/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/home/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml'
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
        __DIR__ . '/../../../templates',
    ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not loaded'? What is rendered instead, or do you get an error?

Comment: please post the controllers code too

Comment: And... Why are not you post the solution? There may be other people with the same problem that you had. (Someone like me: D) @user3753202